# Change CSS Recent Posts widget in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm currently using the Recent Posts widget that comes with WordPress. Is it possible to change the CSS of the links? I want the font to be smaller and not display in bold as it does now. I know it inherits these settings (bold links and font size), but I would like to overwrite them.
Many thanks!

Comment: well we can't help till we can't see issue in live or any working demo so please provide any demo or link. Thanx

Comment: Please don't write the example into a comment. Edit your question. What did you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font styling on the recent posts by adding this to your CSS rules (changing the font size to suit your needs):

```
.widget-inner a {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: I think it looks better having the text bold but the font size down, I'd personally roll with the below but otherwise your answer is spot on j08691.

`.widget-inner a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2;
}`